# custom body class from siteMash in grails

Tags: html, grails, gsp, sitemesh

I have some issue on grails siteMash issue.i need custom class define in every GSP page when i call but in my layout page i am having only  instance of all class.so every page i will change as i need.But i tried pageProperties that not work may be i was on right direction.Kindly see my case;

My html page have:-

```
 <body class="A">
 <body class="A logged-in">
 <body class="B billing logged-in">
 <body class="C logged-in">
 <body class="D popup">
 <body class="E">
 <body class="F logged-in">
 <body class="G logged-in">
 <body class="h logged-in">
```

what i am doing is:-

in my name.gsp //this is my template layout page that have

and in every page i am using as above like   but not getting these body class on html view

it showing layout body class.if i used any specific class in body then all page get same.

thanks in advance,,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sitemesh features for this. Look more at an [article](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html)

Try [pageProperty](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/pageProperty.html) in your layout:

```
<body class="${pageProperty(name: 'body.class')}">
```

Comment: Thanks,for help.what about if <g:if><body class=""></g:if test="user login"><body class="A logged-in"><g:else><body class="A"></g:else> case.here it show error that Grails tag [sitemesh:captureBody] was not closed. like any how </body> is in last.